# adding all char's from a string to an array list (java)

Tags: java

i'm trying to set up a constructor that has a String parameter and adds the individual characters of the String to an ArrayList instance field

```
ArrayList<MyCharacter> charSequence = new ArrayList<MyCharacter>();

public Word(String x) { 
    for (char i : x.toCharArray()) {
        charSequence.add(i);
    }
}
```

i keep getting the error: The method add(MyCharacter) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments 
     (char).

it tells me to change charSequence.add(i); to charSequence.addAll(i); but then i just get another error telling me to change it back to add

suggestions?

Comment: `MyCharacter` and `Character` are not same

Comment: Please provide the total code. MyCharacter class should be given

Comment: Is your issue resolved ? @123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to put the character in your ArrayList, you should have a correct `Generic` type input according to your ArrayList. Since your ArrayList has a Generic Type of `MyCharacter`, you can only put `MyCharacter` class values on the ArrayList. That's why you get it wrong in the beginning. try to change it to `Character` instead. like this:

```
ArrayList<Character> charSequence = new ArrayList<Character>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared the `ArrayList` of the generic type `MyCharacter`, but you are trying to append a `char` to it, these two types are different. Try this :

```
ArrayList<Character> charSequence = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot extend the `Character` class of JDK because it's final. What you can do is you can patch the JDK Character class with your own `Character` class or you can create the complete clone of Character class which is your MyCharacter.[This](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Character.java) is the openjdk Character class. If you want to patch the java.lang.Character class you can create the same package and do as following.

[image]